# Can audio be implemented in a static nested class?

Tags: java, class, audio, static, inner-classes

So I've been trying to implement this audio into my main class. My main class contains other methods which I will not include in order to prevent my post from being too long. I think the code is going wrong because of `out.audio audio = new out.audio ();` because I either placed it in the wrong method or I'm not using the right variables. I'm still very much a beginner coder so I'm already kinda confused with what's going on in my code. What I do know though is that running just the audio class alone (not nested) works.

Am I formatting my nested class correctly and is it possible to nest audio?

```
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.util.Random;
import sun.audio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
class out implements ImageObserver
{
//lots of code and other methods here so I'm going to leave it out
public static class audio extends Thread
{
    out.audio audio = new out.audio ();
    public void run ()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            AudioPlayer MGP = AudioPlayer.player;
            AudioStream BGM;
            AudioData MD;

            ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;

            try
            {
                InputStream test = new FileInputStream ("Music long.au");
                BGM = new AudioStream (test);
                AudioPlayer.player.start (BGM);
                //MD = BGM.getData();
                //loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(MD);

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.print (e.toString ());
            }
            catch (IOException error)
            {
                System.out.print (error.toString ());
            }
            MGP.start (loop);
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep (200000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
            }
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep (1500);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        c = new Console ();
        audio t1 = new audio ();
        t1.start ();
        for (;;)
        {
            c.println ("");
            break;
        }

    } // main method
} // audio class
} //out class
```

Comment: The question seems to be unclear. It's expected that an author has carried out their own research first in order to articulate the problem in a focused, clear way. An appropriate question shouldn't be just a code review request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking when to use nested class, then answer is ***as per your requirement and design***. You are free to use nested class, but sometimes it will make you hard to understand the design and changes to it, if it was not properly done.

I'm quoting [Oracle Official Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

> **Compelling reasons for using nested classes include the following:**
>
> 1. It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place
> 2. It increases encapsulation
> 3. It can lead to more readable and maintainable code

**==Updated==**

As I mentioned, for me it doesn't make sense to have `audio` as inner class, but again its upto your design/requirement, also I'm not sure ***why did you declared your main method inside inner class ??*** So, I was suggesting you

```
class out
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
     //lots of code
    }
}

class ImageImp implements ImageObserver
{
//lots of code and other methods here so I'm going to leave it out

}
```

Then you should take out inner class

```
class audio extends Thread
{

    public void run ()
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

Your design should be simple and should make some sense. Don't try to put everything inside one class until it is really needed.

Comment: I think I am using nested class properly??? But the audio file will not play when I run the program.

Comment: @Nicki IMO, no. You need to take it out.

Comment: but if I take it out and have one class, how do I implement both ImageObserver and extends Thread into one class??

Comment: @Nicki You aren't implementing `ImageObserver` in inner class, i.e. for outer class.  Why don't you just take out and see ??

Comment: you're telling me to not use a nested class which means that I will only have one class. I need {ImageObserver} in my outer class and {extends Thread} in my inner class so if I don't use nested class, how do I put both in one class?? I can't take either of them out

Comment: @Nicki go through my post, I'm not sure, why is it making you so hard to understand. I just said same thing in very simple word. You are trying to  make things complex.

Comment: sorry I'm not an expert coder I'm just a beginner so sorry if I don't understand everything yet. If i just have class audio with extends thread, my images don't run because I need implemented ImageObserver since later I'm using tk.prepareImage to access the image from my files. I want to put everything in one class but I don't know if that's possible. Refer to my latest question if you want more details. Thanks

Comment: @Nicki I'm not sure, what exactly you are trying ? Also, you could implement interface and extends class to one class, what the problem. Please understand this, you main class should be just driving class and avoid writing everything in it. You should write your code in such a way, so that making change to one class shouldn't force you to change entire code.

Comment: @Nicki Please go through my updated post, I have made changes to what I told in simple word. Please note, I can guide you but can't write entire code, as I'm not sure what exactly you are trying and not aware of design. So, you need to take this from here and close this post by accepting the answer.